# why node could be started even though i passed both --validator and --rpc-port?

Tags: substrate-node-template, json-rpc

In this [doc](https://docs.substrate.io/build/remote-procedure-calls/) it says the following:

> By default, the node will refuse to start if you try to expose an RPC
> interface and run a validator node at the same time. The --unsafe-*
> flags allow you to suppress this security measure. Exposing RPC
> interfaces can open up a huge surface of attacks and has to be
> carefully reviewed.

however when I start a local chain using the following command:

```
./target/release/node-template \
--base-path /tmp/alice \
--chain local \
--alice \
--port 30333 \
--ws-port 9945 \
--rpc-port 9933 \
--node-key 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001 \
--telemetry-url "wss://telemetry.polkadot.io/submit/ 0" \
--validator
```

1. it started with no problems, its supposed to refuse to start since its both a validator and is exposing an RPC port but it didn't, why?
2. how to modify the allowed origins?
3. the [doc](https://docs.substrate.io/build/remote-procedure-calls/) also said the following:

> There are quite a few RPC methods that you can use to control the
> node's behavior, but you should avoid exposing. For example, you
> should not expose the following RPC methods:
>
> submit_extrinsic - allows submitting transactions to local pool.

however I'm able to submit extrinsics, the extrinsic gets passed to the node and it gets added to the pool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The flags it is referring to are `--ws-external` and `--rpc-external`. If you try to run your node with these flags and `--validator` it will throw an error:

> Input("--rpc-external and --ws-external options shouldn't be used if the node is running as a validator. Use `--unsafe-rpc-external` or `--rpc-methods=unsafe` if you understand the risks. See the options description for more information.")

see `./target/release/node-template --help` for more info

Comment: you mean if i remove the --alice and create a real chain spec it wouldnt start if keep specifing the rpc and validator options?

Comment: Misunderstood it the first time, changed my answer

Comment: how users are able to get the runtime information and create and send extrinsics if all ports are closed?

Comment: As a network you need at least one rpc node to be able to query this yes

Comment: do you mean as long as that node is not a validator its okey to open the ports and in turn that node will forward the transactions(extrinsics) to the validators, but how so? if all the validator ports are closed, how is this node able to communicate with other validators, in fact how validators will communicate at all?

Comment: First, it is allowed to be a validator and have a RPC interface but just requires a more secure setup. Second, this is through the libp2p network. 
P.S. please comment someone if I'm having it wrong here :)